# How do I collapse an array of numbers into a series of ranges

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
$values=array(2000,2001,2002,3000,3001,3002);
```

I want to return a set of number ranges:

```
$ranges=array(2000-2002,3000-3002);
```

How do I do this?

Comment: You mean as a string range `$ranges=array("2000-2002","3000-3002");`?

Comment: Yes, as a string range.

Answer (score 0):

I think there could be a better solution with array... map / reduce / walk functions, but you can begin with this one.

```
$values = [2000, 2001, 2002, 3000, 3001, 3002];

sort($values);
$result = [];
$start = $prevValue = null;
foreach ($values as value) {
    if ($value - $prevValue > 1) {
        if ($start) {
            $result[] = $start == $prevValue ? $start : $start . '-' . $prevValue;
        }
        $start = $value;
    }
    $prevValue = $value;
}
$result[] = $start == $prevValue ? $start : $start . '-' . $prevValue;
```

Comment: Your code only works when the array of `$values` is sorted ascendingly, That makes the code even better :)

Comment: Well, my code works for the given task. Unfortunately the author didn't provide us with many details and refused to answer a question. Also I think for the unsorted array we will have to sort it first anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Test data output:

```
[2000,2001,2002,3000,3001,3002] => [2000-2002,3000-3002]
[2000,2001,2002,3000,3001,3002,4000] => [2000-2002,3000-3002,4000]
[] => []
[2000] => [2000]
[4001,2000] => [2000,4001]
[4001,2000,2000] => [2000,4001]
```

Here you go:

```
<?php

function groupArrayHelper(array $values, array $groupArray, callable $isWithinRange) {

    if ( !$values ) {
        return $groupArray;
    }

    $lastValueInGroup = (string)$values[0];

    $group = [ $lastValueInGroup ];

    $length = sizeof( $values );

    for ( $i = 1; $i < $length; $i++ ) {
        $currentValue = $values[$i];

        if ( !$isWithinRange( $currentValue, $lastValueInGroup ) ) {
            break;
        }

        $lastValueInGroup = $currentValue;
    }

    if ( ( $lastValueInGroup - $values[0] ) > 0 ) {
        $group[] = (string)$lastValueInGroup;
    }

    $groupArray[] = implode( $group, '-' );

    $moreValues = array_slice( $values, $i );

    return groupArrayHelper( $moreValues, $groupArray, $isWithinRange );
}

function groupArray(array $values) {

    $values = array_unique( $values );
    sort( $values );

    return groupArrayHelper(
            $values,
            [ ],
            function ($x, $y) {
                return ( 1 == $x - $y );
            }
    );
}

function formatArray(array $values) {
    return sprintf( '[%s]', implode( ',', $values ) );
}

$testValues[] = array( 2000, 2001, 2002, 3000, 3001, 3002 );
$testValues[] = array( 2000, 2001, 2002, 3000, 3001, 3002, 4000 );
$testValues[] = array();
$testValues[] = array( 2000 );
$testValues[] = array( 4001, 2000 );
$testValues[] = array( 4001, 2000, 2000 );

array_map( function ($values) {

    $output = groupArray( $values );

    echo formatArray( $values ) . ' => ' . formatArray( $output ) . PHP_EOL;

}, $testValues );
```

Comment: Can you show another variation that works regardless of ascending ordering of the items?